# How to find all documents in a database created by many different users?

Tags: search, view, xpages, relational

I need to find all documents in a database which have been created by x number of users and the result must be a combined (sorted by date) list/collection of documents from all these users.

so I have a multivalue field that contain e.g 100 users, I now need to return a collection programmatically with all the documents in the database that has been created with those users.

worth mentioning here is that the 100 users is dynamic, so in another document there might be 100 different users that is the be used for the search.

I have experimented with the following kind of query, but I believe I run into some kind of limit in the search query. (looks like if the query is to long I get query is not understandable)

FIELD CreatedBy Contains "Thomas" OR FIELD CreatedBy Contains "Peter".... up to 100 more like this

also, finding these documents is triggered by webusers so it must be relative fast.

is there another way to find these documents?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be a view sorted by the creator and a loop with 100 getAllDocumentsByKey. You could run a comparison if you sort the entry field and just walk through the viewnavigator after jumping to the first document.
The result could be added to a folder (you need to manage folders for different query sets and have a cleanup routine) that is sorted how you need it or you sort in memory (think JavaBean). The folder option makes paging to the result easier - you probably don't want to show 10000 results in one go - that would take very long to transmit. You also could use a "result document" where you store the result as JSON and use that as paging source.

Comment: thank you, in a relational database structure a query like this had been very easy and fast. it is really too bad we sometimes end up in these relational nsf limitations where we always need to make slow and  tedious workarounds.

Comment: Thomas looking up 100 keys in an RDBMS is slow and tedious too. You can use the RDBMS access from the Extlib

Answer (score -2):

Easily done with Ytria's ScanEZ. They have trials, I think